# How to get FlatList to Scroll?

Tags: react-native, mobile-development

FlatList Scrolling Not Working

I have tried tinkering with ScrollView and other settings within FlatList to try and get the scrolling to work but it keeps rubberbanding each time I try to scroll.

```
            <FlatList
                style={{flexGrow: 1}}
                data={user}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return <Post item={item} />;
                }}
            />
```

Comment: Do you have enough data in user to make it scroll? You can also try putting `FlatList` inside a `View` and set a height to the `View`.

Comment: Here's an example from expo snack https://snack.expo.dev/@vijaydemonz/flatlist-example?platform=android

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing my image elements inside Post to fixed values rather than percentages.

#Before:

```
postImage: {
    width: '100%', 
    height: '80%',
    borderRadius: 10
}
```

#Fixed:

```
postImage: {
    width: '100%', 
    height: 500,
    borderRadius: 10
}
```

Comment: If the issue was indeed fixed by what you posted, please mark your question as solved.